# Validation rule to change status field on case when checkbox is selected

Tags: community, custom-field, picklist, validation-rule, checkbox

I need I validation rule to change the status picklist on case object to value "Submit to Client" when checkbox with the same "Submit to Client" is ticked. 
Could you please advise how this can be achieved as well as please provide some relevant example.

Comment: Validation rules can only add errors to records being saved. It sounds like you want to use a workflow rule.

Comment: ok, even with workflow rule could you please advise how it can be achieved by giving an exmaple. I'm quite new to the workflow rules.

Comment: Setup > Build > Workflow & Approvals > Workflow Rules; New Rule; Object > Case > Next; Name, created, and every time it's edited, formula evaluates to true, Submit_To_Client__c; Save and next; Add workflow action > New field update; Name, Unique name, Field to Update > Status, A specific value, Submit to Client, Save; Done; Activate.

Comment: thank you martin. How can I mark this question is useful?

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SFSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setup > Build > Workflow & Approvals > Workflow Rules;
2. New Rule;
3. Object > Case > Next;
4. Name, created, and every time it's edited, formula evaluates to true, Submit_To_Client__c;
5. Save and next;
6. Add workflow action > New field update;
7. Name, Unique name, Field to Update > Status, A specific value, Submit to Client, Save;
8. Done;
9. Activate